# Implementing Robot Framework keywords on Selenium: current WebDriver instance is null

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework

I've set up a project using Robot Framework and Maven in Eclipse, with selenium 3.4.0 dependency, robotframework 3.0.2 dependency, markusbernhardt's selenium2library version 1.4.0.8, and robotframework-maven-plugin version 1.4.7.

Now I'm trying to implement my own keywords to extend the selenium2library that RF uses, so I created this class, where I attempt to access the current WebDriver instance so I can access exactly what the RF keywords are accessing:

```
public class Customized {

    private static Selenium2Library s;
    private BrowserManagement b;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Customized() throws ScriptException {
        try {
            Customized.s = (Selenium2Library) Selenium2Library.getLibraryInstance();
        } catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b = s.getBrowserManagement();
        driver=b.getCurrentWebDriver();
    }
}
```

The thing is, whenever I try to use the WebDriver object in any custom keyword I get a null pointer exception. From debugging I can see that driver is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing as you... have you had any luck resolving your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never found a solution to this.